# Bootstrap4 on dropdown show change another parent level div property (CSS)

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

Check this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mfgq2ugr/1/)

I have a `dropdown` and when the `dropdown` is toggled, I want to change  another `div's` background-color (`div's` with classes `.main-content` and `.reqdiv` is this case).

I have tried these selectors `~`, `>`, `+` and I know these won't work in my case. Can anyone please suggest me how to solve this without using JS/JQuery.

```css
.main-content {
  height: 200px;
  width: 100%;
  background: green;
}

.dropdown-menu {
  top: 35px!important;
}

.nav-btn.show~.main-content {
  background: blue;
}

.nav-btn.show>.main-content {
  background: blue;
}

.nav-btn.show+.main-content {
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="row">
  <div class="nav-btn">
    <button class="btn dropdown-toggle " type="button" data-toggle="dropdown"><b>Language</b>
   <span class="caret"></span>
   </button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <li><a href="#">HTML</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">CSS</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">JavaScript</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="#reqdiv">
  //text
</div>
<div class="main-content">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you want dropdown select then change background color in div

```
<select id="evt_color"> 
<option value="#3366CC">Blue</option> 
<option value="#E070D6">Fuchsia</option> 
<option value="#808080">Gray</option> 
<option value="#4bb64f">Green</option> 
<option value="#ed9d2b">Orange</option> 
<option value="#FF9CB3">Pink</option> 
<option value="#EA4A4A">Red</option> 
</select>
<div id="someDiv">Colour sample</div> 


 **Script**
$("#evt_color").change(function() {
    $("#someDiv").css("background-color", $(this).val());
}).change();
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/bNgYm/)

Comment: I need it with pure css

Answer (score 0):

U can simply use specified css classes for changing a background.
`toggleClass` can help on click.

```js
$( "#button" ).on( "click", function() {
    $( ".main-content").toggleClass('blue');
});
```

```css
.main-content{
    height:200px;
    width:100%;
    background:green;
}
.blue{background: blue}
.dropdown-menu{top:35px!important;}
.nav-btn.show ~ .main-content{background:blue;} 
.nav-btn.show > .main-content{background:blue;} 
.nav-btn.show + .main-content{background:blue;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="row">
<div class="nav-btn">
   <button class="btn dropdown-toggle " id="button" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown"><b>Language</b>
   <span class="caret"></span>
   </button>
   <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <li><a href="#">HTML</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">CSS</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">JavaScript</a>
      </li>
   </ul>
</div>
</div>
<div class="#reqdiv">
   //text
</div>
<div class="main-content">
</div>
```

Comment: So u have to change yours HTML. There is no way to select parent in pure CSS. Thats why the are 'cascade'.

Answer (score 0):

If u want to use only css u have to change yours html.
So the background-color changing elements will be siblings to `.nav-btn` element. e.g:

```css
.main-content{
    height:200px;
    width:100%;
    background:green;
}
.dropdown-menu{top:35px!important;}
.nav-btn.show ~ .main-content{background:blue;} 
.nav-btn.show > .main-content{background:blue;} 
.nav-btn.show + .main-content{background:blue;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="nav-btn">
   <button class="btn dropdown-toggle " id="button" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown"><b>Language</b>
   <span class="caret"></span>
   </button>
   <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <li><a href="#">HTML</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">CSS</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">JavaScript</a>
      </li>
   </ul>
</div>
<div class="#reqdiv">
   //text
</div>
<div class="main-content">
</div>
```

Comment: Yeah, but for my case i can't change like that. Drop-down is part of header and main-content is in content part.

Comment: So, sorry. U can't accomplish something like this with pure css. 
Go to https://stackoverflow.com/a/1014958/8615252 to read more.